# can javascript remoting return a subquery?

Tags: javascript-remoting, remote-action

I have a `@remoteaction` method that is a query on contacts with a subquery on a custom object.

When I get the response in javascript I'm using `JSON.stringify()` to examine the response and I'm not getting the subquery results:

```
[Log] [{"Name":"test guy","RecordTypeId":"012G0000000zOTZIA2","CreatedDate":1402533032000,"Id":"003J000000woxFNIAY"},{"Name":"test guy2","RecordTypeId":"012G0000000zOTZIA2","CreatedDate":1402582703000,"Id":"003J000000wpMGFIA2"}] (cordova, line 5180)
```

Has anyone been able to successfully receive the response from a subquery through a `@remoteaction`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sub-queries are returned normally. Here's a simple example:

## Controller

```
public with sharing class remote {
    @RemoteAction public static Account getAccounts() {
        return [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Test' LIMIT 1];
    }
}
```

## Page

```
<apex:page controller="remote">
    <script>
    (function() {
        {!$RemoteAction.remote.getAccounts}(function(d,e) {
            var x = document.querySelector('#content'),
            t = document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(d));
            x.appendChild(t);
        });
    }());
    </script>
    <div id="content"></div>
</apex:page>
```

Output in my org:

```
{"Name":"test","RecordTypeId":"012500000009cP9AAI","Contacts":[{"Name":"test","AccountId":"0015000000saUyLAAU","Id":"00350000022OKpIAAW"}],"Id":"0015000000saUyLAAU"}
```

Comment: yes, sorry I must have been staring at the screen too long, the records I was testing didn't have any sub records..duh